# Sizing and alignment issues with CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am working on a messaging app, but I am having trouble making the conversation float properly. Right now I am using a `section` HTML tag to hold the contents of each message, which contains the image of the sender, the message, the date, and sometimes the reference link.

The issue I am running into is twofold:

1. Messages that float to the right `<section class='right'>`, are not floating to the right of the `.messages` box as I would like them to. I have narrowed this down to being an issue with the `grid-template-columns` on line 145, but I am not sure a different alternative.
2. Messages that are short, such as "hi", should not have a long message box. I figure I'll need to do a minmax, but I'm not exactly sure how I would go about doing this.

Any advice, along with an explanation, would be greatly appreciated. If you are a more visual person, I've attached a screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```css
body {margin: 0}

nav {
  position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100vw; height: 65px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
    color: #5F6368;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

#content {
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px; left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  grid-column-gap: 14px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: 220px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "whochat convo"
    "previews convo";}
/* -------- [WHO CHAT] -------- */
#whochat {
  grid-area: whochat;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;}

#whochat img {
  width: 90px;
  clip-path: circle();}

#whochat .title {
  color: #484848;
  font-weight: 800;}

#whochat .lastseen {
  margin-top: 6px;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;}


/* --------[PREVIEWS]-------- */
#previews {
  grid-area: previews;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden}

#previews .title {
  z-index: 1;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: white}

#previews ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;}

#previews li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 6px}
  #previews li:hover{
    transform: scale(1.007);
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #E9DCF9}

#previews img {
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  clip-path: circle();}

#previews .name {
  font-size: 18px;}

/* -------- [CONVO] -------- */
#convo {
  grid-area: convo;
  border-radius: 14px;
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 60px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "messages"
    "compose";}

#convo .compose {
  grid-area: compose;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 6px;}

.compose textarea {
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  flex: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;}

.compose .button {
  padding: 8px 24px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 26px}

#convo .messages {
  grid-area: messages;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: content-box;}

.messages section {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;}

.messages section.left{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 45px 60%;
  grid-row-gap: 8px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "img msg"
    "img reference"}

.messages section.right{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 45px;
  grid-row-gap: 8px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "msg img"
    "reference img"}

.messages section .pic {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;}

.messages section img {
  grid-area: img;
  width: 30px;
  clip-path: circle();}

.messages section .msg {
  grid-area: msg;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1.5px #CECECE}
  .messages section.left .msg {background-color: white;}
  .messages section.right .msg {background-color: #B488E7;}

.messages section .reference {
  grid-area: reference;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;}

.messages section.right .reference {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse}

.messages section .link {
  margin: 0px 16px;
  font-style: italic;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://classcolonies.com/resources/style.css">
<nav></nav>

<div id='content'>
  <div id='whochat'>
    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
    <div class='title'>John Doe</div>
    <div class='lastseen'>Last Seen: Mon, Aug 14 at 2:00 pm</div>
  </div>
  <div id='previews'>
    <div class='title'>Conversations:</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
        <span class='name'>Elon Musk</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
        <span class='name'>Chris Pratt</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id='convo'>
    <div class='messages'>
      <section class='left'>
        <div class='pic'><img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'></div>
        <span class='msg'>This is an example of a message that would take up multiple lines because of the length. Notice that the image appears on the bottom of the message, which is the desired end result.</span>
        <div class='reference'>
          <span class='date'>1h ago</span>
          <span class='link'><a href=''>Referencing Roanoke Cloze Passage</a></span>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class='right'>
        <div class='pic'><img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/teachers/1.jpg'></div>
        <span class='msg'>This is an example reply. This reply should be floating all the way to the right of the .messages container.</span>
        <div class='reference'>
          <span class='date'>10m ago</span>
          <span class='link'><a href=''>Referencing Roanoke Cloze Passage</a></span>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class='left'>
        <div class='pic'><img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'></div>
        <span class='msg'>This response does not have a link attached.</span>
        <div class='reference'>
          <span class='date'>1h ago</span>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class='compose'>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <button class='button purple-btn'>Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Image of desired end result:**
[image: DESIRED END RESULT]

Comment: Did my solution fix your problem or do you need further input? It it did please mark it as accepted or let me know what you need.

Answer (score 1):

## Recommendation to question 2

<strike>How about `max-content`?</strike> I would not force a big message size on the user. Actually, I'd just make it fit the content. Only set a `max-width` so that it does not break things.

**Edit**:

I have added this here:

```
.messages section .msg {
  [...]
  display: flex;
  justify-self: right;
  [...]
}
```

## Solution to question 1

Did you try `justify-content: right;` on the righthand section?

## Snippet for q1 & q2:

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 65px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
  color: #5F6368;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray
}

#content {
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  grid-column-gap: 14px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: 220px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "whochat convo" "previews convo";
}


/* -------- [WHO CHAT] -------- */

#whochat {
  grid-area: whochat;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

#whochat img {
  width: 90px;
  clip-path: circle();
}

#whochat .title {
  color: #484848;
  font-weight: 800;
}

#whochat .lastseen {
  margin-top: 6px;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;
}


/* --------[PREVIEWS]-------- */

#previews {
  grid-area: previews;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden
}

#previews .title {
  z-index: 1;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: white
}

#previews ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#previews li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 6px
}

#previews li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.007);
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #E9DCF9
}

#previews img {
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  clip-path: circle();
}

#previews .name {
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* -------- [CONVO] -------- */

#convo {
  grid-area: convo;
  border-radius: 14px;
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 60px;
  grid-template-areas: "messages" "compose";
}

#convo .compose {
  grid-area: compose;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 6px;
}

.compose textarea {
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  flex: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.compose .button {
  padding: 8px 24px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 26px
}

#convo .messages {
  grid-area: messages;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.messages section {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.messages section.left {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 45px 60%;
  grid-row-gap: 8px;
  grid-template-areas: "img msg" "img reference"
}

.messages section.right {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 45px;
  grid-row-gap: 8px;
  grid-template-areas: "msg img" "reference img";
  justify-content: right;
}

.messages section .pic {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.messages section img {
  grid-area: img;
  width: 30px;
  clip-path: circle();
}

.messages section .msg {
  grid-area: msg;
  display: flex;
  justify-self: right;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1.5px #CECECE
}

.messages section.left .msg {
  background-color: white;
}

.messages section.right .msg {
  background-color: #B488E7;
}

.messages section .reference {
  grid-area: reference;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.messages section.right .reference {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse
}

.messages section .link {
  margin: 0px 16px;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://classcolonies.com/resources/style.css">
<nav></nav>

<div id='content'>
  <div id='whochat'>
    <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
    <div class='title'>John Doe</div>
    <div class='lastseen'>Last Seen: Mon, Aug 14 at 2:00 pm</div>
  </div>
  <div id='previews'>
    <div class='title'>Conversations:</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
        <span class='name'>Elon Musk</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'>
        <span class='name'>Chris Pratt</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id='convo'>
    <div class='messages'>
      <section class='left'>
        <div class='pic'><img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'></div>
        <span class='msg'>This is an example of a message that would take up multiple lines because of the length. Notice that the image appears on the bottom of the message, which is the desired end result.</span>
        <div class='reference'>
          <span class='date'>1h ago</span>
          <span class='link'><a href=''>Referencing Roanoke Cloze Passage</a></span>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class='right'>
        <div class='pic'><img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/teachers/1.jpg'></div>
        <span class='msg'>This is an example reply. This reply should be floating all the way to the right of the .messages container.</span>
        <div class='reference'>
          <span class='date'>10m ago</span>
          <span class='link'><a href=''>Referencing Roanoke Cloze Passage</a></span>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class='right'>
        <div class='pic'><img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/teachers/1.jpg'></div>
        <span class='msg'>Hi.</span>
        <div class='reference'>
          <span class='date'>10m ago</span>
          <span class='link'><a href=''>Referencing Roanoke Cloze Passage</a></span>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class='left'>
        <div class='pic'><img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/default.png'></div>
        <span class='msg'>This response does not have a link attached.</span>
        <div class='reference'>
          <span class='date'>1h ago</span>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class='compose'>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <button class='button purple-btn'>Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Simple fix for the first problem, thank you! I feel silly not thinking of that. Any suggestions for the second problem with the sizing of the response box?

Comment: How about `max-content`? I would not force a big-message-size on the user. Actually, I'd just make it fit the content (no extra styling). Only set a `max-width` so that it does not break things.

Comment: What would this look like? When I change the ```grid-template-columns``` to be ```45px 1fr``` and then apply a ```max-width``` to the actual ```.msg```, this causes the "right" message to resume floating left. Gah!

Comment: @Johnathan Have a look again. I have updated the snippet. This should work. You might need to tweak & test it a bit more.

Comment: @Johnathan I would not use grid for low-level detail-styling. Problem is that it behaves table-like in nature. You are most of the time more "flex-ible" (pun intended) with flexbox - at least that is from my experience. I normally do the big wireframe-layout in grid and the components in flexbox, unless I really show something like uniform card layouts. Sometimes a combo works best - otherwise trial and error :)